# Coupled Oscillator Period

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, oscillators, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

I was studying an example of a coupled oscillator the other day, namely two identical masses attached to three springs, the lateral ones of which with the same elastic constant, when I came across the claim that:

> “If the ratio of the normal modes periods“ is rational then the system moves periodically, that is, $(x_1(t), x_2(t))$ is a periodic function, where $x_1$, $x_2$ refer to the positions of the masses.”

How can one prove this claim?

Any help or hint is always highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a rational ratio of periods, $T_1/T_2=n/m$,    means that  the periods are $T_1=nT_0$ and $T_2=mT_0$ for some  integers $n$, $m$. We can suppose  that $n$ and $m$ have no common integer factor (we could cancel it out if there were such a factor). In this case the  motion will   exactly repeat for the first time after time  $T_3=nm T_0$ because  $T_3= mT_1=nT_2$. The motion is therefore periodic with period $T_3$.